# How to mock HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages

Tags: httpcontext

I am trying to mock `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages`

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks
Harish

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper for it that implements some interface and substitute it with fake one in tests.

Or look here if you are using MVC
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx